# r - Calculate shortest distance between 2 points in a delaunay triangulation

Tags: r, shortest-path, dijkstra, delaunay

Currently I'm working with spatial data and applied a Delaunay triangulation on my data points. I additionally calculated the geodesic distances on the WGS84 ellipsoid for every edge (connection between 2 points) in the triangulation. Now I'm going to search the shortest path between every 2 points in the generated graph and calculate the path distance. The shortest distance should thus be calculated as the sum over all edge distances.

Below is a minimal working example:

```r
library(deldir)

set.seed(31)
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
d <- deldir(x, y)  #preforms tesselation & Delaunay triangulation

#Calculate edge distances (for reasons of simplicity I calculate here Euclidean distances)
geodists <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(d$delsgs)) {
  geodists[i] <- sqrt((x[d$delsgs[i,5]] - x[d$delsgs[i,6]])^2 + (y[d$delsgs[i,5]] - y[d$delsgs[i,6]])^2)
}

#Plot data
plot(d, wlines="triang")
```

However, I have no idea how I can perform the shortest path search on the deldir object I created. Thus, I'd be very happy if you could provide some solutions for my problem:

1. How can I identify which edges are involved in the shortest path between point A and B?
2. How can I then efficiently calculate the path distance matrix?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are some path finding algorithms. One of them is A* ([Wikipedia Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm))
Maybe this helps you. 
You can replace the regularly ordered points in an Euclidean Metric by the delaunay points of your collection of points. 
Then always go to the next neighbor, which is closest to the finish point.